# My jquery div is appearing then disappearing

Tags: jquery

I took over code from another developer. There is a small image and comment box that briefly shows when the page loads then disappears. It should be visible all of the time. I think it is related to some jquery on the page but I have no clue how it works.

Here is the div that appears and disappears:

```
<a href="#comments_box_b34af24f72ea4d630292ff3a4c4fb4e6" class="comments_link" style="margin-left:5px">
    <img src="/images/user_comment.png" border="0" alt="Comments">
</a>

<div id="comments_box_b34af24f72ea4d630292ff3a4c4fb4e6" style="display:none”>
    <label style="font-weight:normal; font-size:14px;">Comments:</label>
    <textarea name="comments_b34af24f72ea4d630292ff3a4c4fb4e6"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the jquery on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".comments_link").toggle(function(){
        $($(this).attr('href')).show('slow');
    },function(){
        $($(this).attr('href')).hide('slow');
    });
});
```

Why does it not stay visible and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you check inspect element in chrome or firebug in FF or something similar to see where your display:hidden appears?

Comment: Are you missing the opening declaration of the `div` or are you talking about the inner one with `display:none`?

Comment: I believe the divs are balance OK. I may have a bad copy & paste.

Comment: "I took over code from another developer." And so it begins X-P

Answer (score 3):

First of all, when taking code of other developers, always check the date. The `toggle` you took was the `click toggle` of jQuery, which is now deprecated and removed.

Now `.toggle` is used only for the visibility purpose. it accept 2 argument: duration and callback.

Here what you code is doing :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".comments_link").toggle(function(){ //You set duration to a function, it execute a function
        $($(this).attr('href')).show('slow'); //The function show your element
    },function(){ //Set a callback, so after toggle finish, it call that function
        $($(this).attr('href')).hide('slow'); //The function hide the element
    });
});
```

What you want is either

A) show the element on load :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var href = $(".comments_link").attr('href');
    $(href).show('slow');
});
```

B) show/hide element on click :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".comments_link").click(function(){
        $($(this).attr('href')).toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to change your jQuery to

```
$(".comments_link").click(function(){
    if($($(this).attr('href')).css("display") == "none")
    {
        $($(this).attr('href')).show('slow');
    }
    else
    {
        $($(this).attr('href')).hide('slow');
    }
});
```

I think this is what you want..

See here for a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Callie_/gVF83/)**

If you want hidden as default just add

```
$(function(){
    $($(".comments_link").attr('href')).css("display", "none");
});
```

Like you can see in this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Callie_/gVF83/1/)**

Comment: "Why does it not stay visible and how can I fix it?" -- While this solves OP's *problem*, it does not answer OP's *question*. ;)

Comment: @CaseyFalk Yeah, I see, I misunderstood the question.. My fault :-(

Comment: Thanks. I think was pretty close. The divs are all showing now by default vs. being hidden. If I want them to be hidden by defaut and toggle visible do I just reverse the hide and show statements. Also - how do I give you props for this. This is first stack overflow question.

Comment: @PatrickAllmond For hidden as default, check my answer. I updated it. :-) You can click on the up arrow left to my answer en click on the checkmark so other people know this is the anwser ;)

Comment: Ugh. It says I don't have enough reputation yet to give you an upvote. Sorry.

Comment: No problem, just click on the checkmark then so other people who find this problem can see what the solution was. :-)